# Regular expression: Detect multiple occurrences of the new line character in sequence and replace with one new line

Tags: regex

I need a regex which will detect multiple occurrences of the new line character in sequence and replace with one new line.  Is this possible?

many thanks

Comment: Please provide the code and regex that you've tried and show the research that you've done on this topic.

Comment: I could copy n paste lots of regular expressions I have tried, however I don't see the value in that.

Comment: If you haven't read it already, here's a commonly cited article on the value of showing what you're tried: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: I still disgree.  This would be more appropriate with a complex problem.  Listing a load of regular expressions which don't achieve what I want would be pointless given the triviality of the problem.  It's like asking for a red-like color, and saying well, I have tried orange, yellow and maroon, but they didn't work out.  I think there should be scope on SO for simple questions and simple answers.  Regex is a bit like that, especially if you don't use it everyday.  So let's all relax and quell our OCD / pedantic urges and get on with more interesting problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, for example:

```
(\r?\n)+
```

Replace with the content of first capturing group.

Comment: thanks, although it's actually multiple occurrences of "\n" I'm wanting to replace with a single "\n". However, I'll try to adapt your regex. thanks

Comment: @Boomerangertanger, that will match multiple occurrences of `\n`, and also multiple occurrences of `\r\n`. If you are only interested in `\n` you can use `\n+` replaced with `\n`.